# CSS transition only works once in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having an issue with `CSS transitions` and different browsers. The following Fiddle works fine on IE (the text on the right hand side correctly fades in when you hover over the items on the left and you can switch to other items with the transition still firing on every new hover), but for some reason FF and Chrome will no longer do the `transition` after selecting one of the items on the left.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1c53c7y3/1/)

The CSS transition code:

```
.FAQItemText.active, .FAQItemTextDark.active, .solutionText.active {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1500ms ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1500ms ease;
    transition: opacity 1500ms ease;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Please can anyone help me fix it to make it work on all browsers?

Thanks

Comment: try to change your code in this code structure: http://jsfiddle.net/e6p2mubp/1/

Comment: The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not the other browsers, your code is wrong."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions, after a while of googling I came across [this](http://api.jquery.com/show/) which seems to do the trick.

So I changed my js code from this:

```
function ShowSlide(slide, slideItem) {
    //Reset page
    resetAllHighlights(slide);
    //Show needed ones.
    jQuery('#slideItem' + slide + slideItem).show();
    jQuery('#slideItem' + slide + slideItem).addClass("active");
    jQuery('#menuItem' + slide + slideItem).addClass("itemSelected");
}
```

To this:

```
function ShowSlide(slide, slideItem) {
    //Reset page
    resetAllHighlights(slide);
    //Show needed ones.
    jQuery('#slideItem' + slide + slideItem).show(0);
    jQuery('#slideItem' + slide + slideItem).addClass("active");
    jQuery('#menuItem' + slide + slideItem).addClass("itemSelected");
}
```

And it now works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

A CSS **transition** can't repeat. if you want something that repeat, use a CSS **animation**

Link : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your code was overly complicated and there are much simpler ways of doing what you're trying to achieve. I rewrote your `JS` to work like it should, altered your `CSS` classes and rules to better suit the purpose and cleaned up your `DOM` a little bit also.

Check out the code below, where I have explained what changes I've made:

```js
$(function(){
    //select all the link elements and add needed event handlers:
    $(".leftSlidePanel>a")
       .mouseenter(preview)
       .mouseleave(preview)
       .click(selectSlide);
});

function preview(event){
    // This is the slide the element you clicked on links to:
    var targetSlide=$(event.currentTarget).attr("href"); 
    // Let's make a selector to select the .leftItem inside the link you hovered and our target slide:
    var previewedItem=$(event.currentTarget).find(".leftItem").add(targetSlide);
    // and another selector to select all the .leftItems and .FAQItemTexts aparat from the ones being targeted:
    var hiddenItems=$(".leftItem, .FAQItemText").not(previewedItem);
    // Next add or remove classes from our selected items depending on wheter it was mouseeneter or mouseout:
    if(event.type=="mouseenter"){
        previewedItem.addClass("previewed");
        hiddenItems.addClass("hidden");
    }else{
        previewedItem.removeClass("previewed");
        hiddenItems.removeClass("hidden");
    }
}

function selectSlide(event){
    // Prevent default behaviour of clicking a link:
    event.preventDefault();
    // Remove class selected from all .leftItems and .FAQItemTexts:
    $(".leftItem, .FAQItemText").removeClass("selected");
    // And add said class to targeted elements:
    $(event.currentTarget).find(".leftItem").add($(event.currentTarget).attr("href")).addClass("selected");
}
```

```css
.slideContentContainer {
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:1050px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:80px;
}
.leftSlidePanel {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    padding-top:29px;
}
.rightSlidePanel {
    float:right;
    width:70%;
    padding-top:29px;
}
.leftItem {
    color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
    font-family:"Helvetica W01 Cn" !important;
}
.leftItem h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top:5px;
}
/* this is how your links on the left will look like when they're selected or previewed: */
.leftItem.selected, .leftItem.previewed {
    color: rgb(227, 114, 22);
}
.dark.selected {
    color: rgb(49, 49, 50);
}
/* This is the style your FAQItemText has normally and when another item is being previewed: */
.FAQItemText, .FAQItemText.selected.hidden {
    width: 95%;
    opacity: 0;
    float:right;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top:29px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: rgb(227, 114, 22);
    font-family:"Helvetica W01 Cn" !important;
    display:none;
}
/* Instead of creating another class with almost the same rules as another, create a subclass: */
.FAQItemText.dark {
    color: rgb(49, 49, 50);
}
/* This is the style your FAQItemText will have when it's either selected or previewed: */
.FAQItemText.selected, .FAQItemText.previewed{
    opacity: 1;
    display:block;
    /* Firefox and IE support animations without vendor prefixes, so -webkit- is the only one you'll need */
    -webkit-animation: fade 1.5s 1;
    animation: fade 1.5s 1;
}

/* using display:block wile transitioning opacity can often doesn't give you the effect you'd want, but this can be fixed by using an animation instead: */
@-webkit-keyframes fade{
    0%   {display:none;  opacity:0;}
    1%   {display:block; opacity:0;}
    100% {display:block; opacity:1;}
}
@-keyframes fade{
    0%   {display:none;  opacity:0;}
    1%   {display:block; opacity:0;}
    100% {display:block; opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" id="faqs">
    <div class="slideContentContainer">
        <div class="leftSlidePanel">
            <a href="#slideItem11"><div id="menuItem11" class="leftItem selected"><h4>1</h4></div></a>
            <a href="#slideItem12"><div id="menuItem12" class="leftItem"><h4>2</h4></div></a>
            <a href="#slideItem13"><div id="menuItem13" class="leftItem"><h4>3</h4></div></a>
            <a href="#slideItem14"><div id="menuItem14" class="leftItem"><h4>4</h4></div></a>
            <a href="#slideItem15"><div id="menuItem15" class="leftItem"><h4>5</h4></div></a>
            <a href="#slideItem16"><div id="menuItem16" class="leftItem"><h4>6</h4></div></a>
        </div>
        <div class="rightSlidePanel">
            <div id="slideItem11" class="FAQItemText selected">BLAH 1 BLAH.</div>
            <div id="slideItem12" class="FAQItemText">BLAH 2 BLAH.</div>
            <div id="slideItem13" class="FAQItemText">BLAH 3 BLAH.</div>
            <div id="slideItem14" class="FAQItemText">BLAH 4 BLAH.</div>
            <div id="slideItem15" class="FAQItemText">BLAH 5 BLAH.</div>
            <div id="slideItem16" class="FAQItemText">BLAH 6 BLAH.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @ilpo-oksanen, unless I am missing something this doesn't seem to work, I created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eo8rc1gq/) with your code, but it doesn't do the transition/animation at all now?